# DataSnapshot Data show null in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to read data from firebase database but each time DataSnapshot  is giving Null value and i was able to update data but not able to read it .

can any one help me

```
private void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        UserInformation uInfo = new UserInformation();
        uInfo.setName(ds.child(userID).getValue(UserInformation.class).getName()); //set the name
        uInfo.setEmail(ds.child(userID).getValue(UserInformation.class).getEmail()); //set the email
        uInfo.setPhone_num(ds.child(userID).getValue(UserInformation.class).getPhone_num()); //set the phone_num

        //display all the information
        Log.d(TAG, "showData: name: " + uInfo.getName());
        Log.d(TAG, "showData: email: " + uInfo.getEmail());
        Log.d(TAG, "showData: phone_num: " + uInfo.getPhone_num());
        Toast.makeText(this,uInfo.getName().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        ArrayList<String> array  = new ArrayList<>();
        array.add(uInfo.getName());
        array.add(uInfo.getEmail());
        array.add(uInfo.getPhone_num());
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

I call this function from

```
 myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // This method is called once with the initial value and again
            // whenever data at this location is updated.
            try {
                showData(dataSnapshot);
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                toastMessage("datasnapshow Exception"+e);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

This will give me Null Exception. I am stuck with this problem can any one help me out. The database structure:

```
{
    myfirebase284
        m0p7r9ryj5Mr22NVWUt1DcYTjqG2
            email: "pema@gmail.com"
            name: "pema"
            phone_num: 9990480514
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post a picture of your database structure?

Comment: Can you please use a json file? Or in stead of that, a picture?

Comment: Any good tutorial that show how to read data from firebased @Alex Mamo

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to display data, you don't need to create a new object of your `UserInformation` class. You need to get `UserInformation` object from the `dataSnapshot` object. So in order to achieve this please make the following changes. Change this line:

```
UserInformation uInfo = new UserInformation();
```

with

```
UserInformation uInfo = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserInformation.class);
String name = uInfo.getName();
String email = uInfo.getEmail();
String phone_num = uInfo.getPhone_num();
```

Considering that `getName()`, `getEmail()` and `getPhone_num()` are the public getters from your model class.

Also get the `ArrayList<String> array  = new ArrayList<>();` out from the for loop.

According to your database structure to read your data using the `String` class, please use this code:

```
DatabaseReference yourRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(userId);
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String email = (String) dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue();
        String name = (String) dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue();
        String phone_num = (String) dataSnapshot.child("phone_num").getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
yourRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

In which `userId` is the unique generated id by the `push()` method.

If you want to learn more about reading and writing  into a Firebase database, please chceck the official [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yap problem is with the retriving as i was able to get the data  System.out.println("the database is----->"+ds.getValue()); where ds is the datasnapshot but how to get it one by one and show it ...any help